# Convert C# soap client to PHP (issues in casting complex types)

Tags: c#, php, web-services, soap

Good day all. I'm creating a PHP SOAP client using a C# as a reference and example (this is the only documentation I recieved).

actually I've got some problems with this C# code (I don't know C# at all):

```
SI = SessionID.SessionId.ToString();

            My_Arx_Search.ARX_SearchSoapClient arx_Search = new My_Arx_Search.ARX_SearchSoapClient();

            //Estrazione della Dm_Profile_Search data il codice della classe documentale 
            var search = arx_Search.Dm_Profile_Search_Get_New_Instance_By_TipiDocumentoCodice(SI, "MEDICINA.REFERTO");
            //imposto i parametri AOO
            search.Aoo.Operatore = My_Arx_Search.Dm_Base_Search_Operatore_String.Uguale;
            search.Aoo.Valore = "001"; //001 (che sta per sant andrea)

            // imposto il filtro campo aggiuntivo    
            var aggSearch = (from x in search.Aggiuntivi where x.ExternalId == "codicefiscale" select x).FirstOrDefault();
            if (aggSearch == null) throw new Exception(string.Format("Impossibile trovare il campo aggiuntivo con externalId= '{0}' (Search)", "codicefiscale"));

            //Per Esempio:  imposto il filtro sapendo che il campo aggiuntivo è string         
            My_Arx_Search.Field_String campo = ((My_Arx_Search.Field_String)aggSearch); //that's a php cast (int)$foo;
            campo.Operatore = My_Arx_Search.Dm_Base_Search_Operatore_String.Uguale;
            campo.Valore = "DFLMHLD15GGFD...";
```

Actually I've translate in PHP this part:

```
$resSearch = $cSearch->Dm_Profile_Search_Get_New_Instance_By_TipiDocumentoCodice(array('sessionId' => $sesId, 'DmTipiDocumentoCodice' => "MEDICINA.REFERTO"));
if (is_soap_fault($resSearch)) {
    echo "must login again<br>";        
}

$resSearch->Aoo->Operatore ="Uguale";
$resSearch->Aoo->Valore ="001";
```

but honestly, I feel I'm loosing something.
is there a method or something that could help me translating this client?

These are the lines I really can't convert:

```
// imposto il filtro campo aggiuntivo    
            var aggSearch = (from x in search.Aggiuntivi where x.ExternalId == "codicefiscale" select x).FirstOrDefault();
            if (aggSearch == null) throw new Exception(string.Format("Impossibile trovare il campo aggiuntivo con externalId= '{0}' (Search)", "codicefiscale"));

            //Per Esempio:  imposto il filtro sapendo che il campo aggiuntivo è string         
            My_Arx_Search.Field_String campo = ((My_Arx_Search.Field_String)aggSearch); //that's a php cast (int)$foo;
            campo.Operatore = My_Arx_Search.Dm_Base_Search_Operatore_String.Uguale;
            campo.Valore = "DFLMHLD15GGFD...";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$aggSearch = '';
foreach ($row as $resSearch->Aggiuntivi) {
    if ($row->ExternalId == 'codicefiscale') {
        $aggSearch = $row;
        break;
    }
}
if (empty($aggSearch)) {
    throw new \Exception(sprintf("Impossibile trovare il campo aggiuntivo con externalId= '%s' (Search)", 'codicefiscale' ));
}
```